# Workaround for lack of "hide sensitive content" setting for lockscreen notifications in CyanogenMod 13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, lock-screens

I have recently installed CyanogenMod 13 on an Android One phone (i.e. the 'sprout' version of CM).  I installed the release version.  In the notification settings, under "when locked", I was surprised to find that the setting "hide sensitive content" is missing.  I.e. I can either choose to have all my notifications be completely visible, or I can choose to have them be completely hidden.  Neither of those is a convenient setting.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should report this to CM's issue tracker and see what they reply with. You could try a different ROM in the meantime. Or you could one of the dozens of lock screen replacement apps on the play store, but then they can also access all your notifications, even if they don't show them on the lock screen (via accessibility permissions).

Answer (score 2):

The problem turns out to be that this option only shows up if the lock screen is set to a PIN / password / etc.  If it is set to swipe, it doesn't show up.  This is not exactly intuitive but I guess it makes sense at some level.